# could I make folder in res with any name that I want?

Tags: android, adt

I just notice that aapt make a R class that has so many subclass that are the same as android res folder . can I make a folder in res with name  that is not of those subclass of R.java and use it as a res with  .xml file that I put in it ?

Comment: What is stoping you from trying it?

Comment: I try it but the folder that  I make disappear so I change project View to package and I could see the folder that I just make . when I use that in code the R get red color . If I cannot Do that why tha make it possible to make folder with any name ? above  question was for better understanding the basics

Answer (score 0):

The organization of the res folder is special for Android, and how you create those folders has a ton to do with how the resources are located ultimately.

You cannot create ANY folder, but you could create ANY named xml file, and add specific resources in there.

Check out this link for info about how to use this powerful feature of Android (using resources effectively is important for Android Devs).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources